# how to remove a letter that shows multiple times if you only want on of it to show up?

Tags: python, string

Can someone help me to go from  this:

```
'BANANARAMA'
```

to

```
'BANRM'
```

in Python?
I already tried this:

```
def reduceer(woord):
    return ''.join(c for c, in list(woord()))
```

but it won't work

Answer (score 2):

A few [pointers](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/pointers.png):

1. `woord` is not callable, so `woord()` will throw a `TypeError`.
2. `c,` is trying to unpack a sequence of length one. This will work with lines like `c, = 'x'` but is pointless because characters (over which you are trying to iterate) already have length one.
3. There is nothing in your code to remove the duplicates, `list(my_string)` will just build a list of characters.
4. In addition to not removing duplicates, `list` does not do anything useful here, because strings are already iterable.

I won't rewrite your function, but here's the lazy man's approach for CPython 3.6 (or any 3.7 version):

```
>>> ''.join(dict.fromkeys('BANANARAMA'))
'BANRM'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create a new list, add every character only once (by checking if it is already in that list) and use [join](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to create a new string

```
def reducer(word):
  res = []
  for ch in word:
    if(ch not in res):
      res.append(ch)
  return ''.join(res)
```

Test it:

```
print(reducer('BANANARAMA'))
```

Output:

```
BANRM
```